# my program keeps failing to build because it trys to find a value in `lblUp1lvl`

Tags: windows, vb.net, msbuild

**my code was working fine until today when it isn't working (everthing running without errors)**
and `lblUp1lvl` is set to `0`

## here is my code:

(I use the `better comments` extention so that's why some of the comments look funky)

### Idle Time Waster.vb

```
Public Class formIdleTimeWaster

    '*When User Loads the Program
    Private Sub FormIdleTimeWaster_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODOSet cps value
        Cps = 0
        ClickValue = 0
        timerCPS.Interval = 1000
        timerCPS.Start()
        'todo Update variables from save file
    End Sub

    '*When User Clicks the Button
    Private Sub BtnUserClick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUserClick.Click
        UserClicked()
        lblTotalHW.Text = CStr(Total)
    End Sub

    '*Every Second this code runs
    Private Sub TimerCPS_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerCPS.Tick
        AddCPS()

        'Show CPS Value
        lblCPS.Text = CStr(Cps)
    End Sub
    '?Adds 1 extra of what is meant to be added
    '*User clicks Click Value upgrade button
    Private Sub btnUp1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUp1.Click
        Upgrade(Up1lvl, Up1Cost)
        Up1Update()

        lblUp1Cost.Text = CStr(Up1Cost)
        lblUp1lvl.Text = CStr(Up1lvl)
        lblClickValue.Text = CStr(Up1lvl)
    End Sub

    '*User clicks CPS upgrade value
    Private Sub btnUp2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUp2.Click
        Upgrade(Up2lvl, Up2Cost)
        Up2Update()

        lblUp2Cost.Text = CStr(Up2Cost)
        lblUp2lvl.Text = CStr(Up2lvl)
        lblCPS.Text = CStr(Up2lvl)
    End Sub
End Class
```

### Functions.vb

```
Public Module Functions
    '*Define All Needed Values
    Public Total As Integer
    Public Cps As Integer
    Public ClickValue As Integer
    Public Up1lvl As Integer = 0
    Public Up1Cost As Integer
    Public Up2lvl As Integer = 0
    Public Up2Cost As Integer

    '*When User Clicks the Button
    Function UserClicked()
        Total = ClickValue + Total
        Return Total
    End Function

    '*Calculate Cps
    Function AddCPS()
        'Add Cps to HWTotal
        Total = Total + Cps
        Return Total
    End Function

    '*Upgrade
    Sub Upgrade(ByRef lvl, ByRef Cost)
        If Total >= Cost Then
            Total = CInt(Total) - Cost
            lvl = lvl + 1
        Else
            MsgBox("Not Enough time wasted, go do nothing some more to get better at doing nothing", 0, "to early!")
        End If
    End Sub

    'FIXME:the program seems to have difficulty when i try to bring ``Up1Cost`` and ``Up2Cost`` into the function
    '*xUpdate Upgrade Values
    'xFunction Update(ByRef Cost As Integer, ByRef lvl As Integer, ByRef Value As Integer)
    'x    Cost = lvl * 10
    'x    Value = lvl
    'xReturn Cost & lvl & Value
    'xEnd Function

    '*Update Click Value Upgrade Values
    Sub Up1Update()
        Up1Cost = Up1lvl * 10
        ClickValue = Up1lvl
    End Sub

    '*Update CPS Upgrade Values
    Sub Up2Update()
        Up2Cost = Up2lvl * 10
        Cps = Up2lvl
    End Sub
End Module
```

### Idle Time Waster.Designer.vb

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class formIdleTimeWaster
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Dim gbStats As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
        Dim lblHWPerClickTitle As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Dim lblCPSTitle As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Dim lblTotalHWTitle As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Dim lblUp1lvlName As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Dim lblUp2lvlName As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Dim lblUp1CostName As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Dim lblUp2CostName As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.lblClickValue = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblCPS = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblTotalHW = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.btnUserClick = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.timerCPS = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer(Me.components)
        Me.lblUp2lvl = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.btnUp1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.btnUp2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.lblUp1Cost = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblUp2Cost = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.NotifyIcon1 = New System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(Me.components)
        Me.lblUp1lvl = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        gbStats = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
        lblHWPerClickTitle = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        lblCPSTitle = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        lblTotalHWTitle = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        lblUp1lvlName = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        lblUp2lvlName = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        lblUp1CostName = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        lblUp2CostName = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        gbStats.SuspendLayout()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'gbStats
        '
        gbStats.Controls.Add(Me.lblClickValue)
        gbStats.Controls.Add(Me.lblCPS)
        gbStats.Controls.Add(Me.lblTotalHW)
        gbStats.Controls.Add(lblHWPerClickTitle)
        gbStats.Controls.Add(lblCPSTitle)
        gbStats.Controls.Add(lblTotalHWTitle)
        gbStats.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(217, 8)
        gbStats.Name = "gbStats"
        gbStats.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(208, 114)
        gbStats.TabIndex = 0
        gbStats.TabStop = False
        gbStats.Text = "Stats"
        '
        'lblClickValue
        '
        Me.lblClickValue.AutoSize = True
        Me.lblClickValue.CausesValidation = False
        Me.lblClickValue.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(153, 82)
        Me.lblClickValue.Name = "lblClickValue"
        Me.lblClickValue.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 15)
        Me.lblClickValue.TabIndex = 5
        Me.lblClickValue.Text = "0"
        '
        'lblCPS
        '
        Me.lblCPS.AutoSize = True
        Me.lblCPS.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(166, 52)
        Me.lblCPS.Name = "lblCPS"
        Me.lblCPS.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 15)
        Me.lblCPS.TabIndex = 4
        Me.lblCPS.Text = "0"
        '
        'lblTotalHW
        '
        Me.lblTotalHW.AutoSize = True
        Me.lblTotalHW.CausesValidation = False
        Me.lblTotalHW.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(132, 21)
        Me.lblTotalHW.Name = "lblTotalHW"
        Me.lblTotalHW.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 15)
        Me.lblTotalHW.TabIndex = 3
        Me.lblTotalHW.Text = "0"
        '
        'lblHWPerClickTitle
        '
        lblHWPerClickTitle.AutoSize = True
        lblHWPerClickTitle.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(14, 82)
        lblHWPerClickTitle.Name = "lblHWPerClickTitle"
        lblHWPerClickTitle.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(133, 15)
        lblHWPerClickTitle.TabIndex = 2
        lblHWPerClickTitle.Text = "Hours Wasted Per Click:"
        '
        'lblCPSTitle
        '
        lblCPSTitle.AutoSize = True
        lblCPSTitle.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(14, 52)
        lblCPSTitle.Name = "lblCPSTitle"
        lblCPSTitle.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(146, 15)
        lblCPSTitle.TabIndex = 1
        lblCPSTitle.Text = "Hours Wasted per Second:"
        '
        'lblTotalHWTitle
        '
        lblTotalHWTitle.AutoSize = True
        lblTotalHWTitle.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(14, 21)
        lblTotalHWTitle.Name = "lblTotalHWTitle"
        lblTotalHWTitle.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(112, 15)
        lblTotalHWTitle.TabIndex = 0
        lblTotalHWTitle.Text = "Total Hours Wasted:"
        '
        'lblUp1lvlName
        '
        lblUp1lvlName.AutoSize = True
        lblUp1lvlName.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(217, 149)
        lblUp1lvlName.Name = "lblUp1lvlName"
        lblUp1lvlName.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(37, 15)
        lblUp1lvlName.TabIndex = 2
        lblUp1lvlName.Text = "Level:"
        '
        'lblUp2lvlName
        '
        lblUp2lvlName.AutoSize = True
        lblUp2lvlName.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(217, 175)
        lblUp2lvlName.Name = "lblUp2lvlName"
        lblUp2lvlName.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(37, 15)
        lblUp2lvlName.TabIndex = 4
        lblUp2lvlName.Text = "Level:"
        '
        'lblUp1CostName
        '
        lblUp1CostName.AutoSize = True
        lblUp1CostName.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(291, 149)
        lblUp1CostName.Name = "lblUp1CostName"
        lblUp1CostName.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(34, 15)
        lblUp1CostName.TabIndex = 8
        lblUp1CostName.Text = "Cost:"
        '
        'lblUp2CostName
        '
        lblUp2CostName.AutoSize = True
        lblUp2CostName.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(291, 175)
        lblUp2CostName.Name = "lblUp2CostName"
        lblUp2CostName.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(34, 15)
        lblUp2CostName.TabIndex = 9
        lblUp2CostName.Text = "Cost:"
        '
        'btnUserClick
        '
        Me.btnUserClick.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
        Me.btnUserClick.Name = "btnUserClick"
        Me.btnUserClick.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(199, 110)
        Me.btnUserClick.TabIndex = 1
        Me.btnUserClick.Text = "Play Idle Game"
        Me.btnUserClick.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'timerCPS
        '
        '
        'lblUp2lvl
        '
        Me.lblUp2lvl.AutoSize = True
        Me.lblUp2lvl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(260, 175)
        Me.lblUp2lvl.Name = "lblUp2lvl"
        Me.lblUp2lvl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 15)
        Me.lblUp2lvl.TabIndex = 5
        Me.lblUp2lvl.Text = "0"
        '
        'btnUp1
        '
        Me.btnUp1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 143)
        Me.btnUp1.Name = "btnUp1"
        Me.btnUp1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(199, 27)
        Me.btnUp1.TabIndex = 6
        Me.btnUp1.Text = "Upgrade Click"
        Me.btnUp1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'btnUp2
        '
        Me.btnUp2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 169)
        Me.btnUp2.Name = "btnUp2"
        Me.btnUp2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(199, 27)
        Me.btnUp2.TabIndex = 7
        Me.btnUp2.Text = "Upgrade Passive time wasting"
        Me.btnUp2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'lblUp1Cost
        '
        Me.lblUp1Cost.AutoSize = True
        Me.lblUp1Cost.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(330, 149)
        Me.lblUp1Cost.Name = "lblUp1Cost"
        Me.lblUp1Cost.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 15)
        Me.lblUp1Cost.TabIndex = 10
        Me.lblUp1Cost.Text = "0"
        '
        'lblUp2Cost
        '
        Me.lblUp2Cost.AutoSize = True
        Me.lblUp2Cost.CausesValidation = False
        Me.lblUp2Cost.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(331, 175)
        Me.lblUp2Cost.Name = "lblUp2Cost"
        Me.lblUp2Cost.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 15)
        Me.lblUp2Cost.TabIndex = 11
        Me.lblUp2Cost.Text = "0"
        '
        'NotifyIcon1
        '
        Me.NotifyIcon1.Text = "NotifyIcon1"
        Me.NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
        '
        'lblUp1lvl
        '
        Me.lblUp1lvl.AutoSize = True
        Me.lblUp1lvl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(260, 149)
        Me.lblUp1lvl.Name = "lblUp1lvl"
        Me.lblUp1lvl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 15)
        Me.lblUp1lvl.TabIndex = 12
        Me.lblUp1lvl.Text = "0"
        '
        'formIdleTimeWaster
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(7.0!, 15.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(440, 207)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblUp1lvl)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblUp2Cost)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblUp1Cost)
        Me.Controls.Add(lblUp2CostName)
        Me.Controls.Add(lblUp1CostName)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnUp2)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnUp1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblUp2lvl)
        Me.Controls.Add(lblUp2lvlName)
        Me.Controls.Add(lblUp1lvlName)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnUserClick)
        Me.Controls.Add(gbStats)
        Me.Name = "formIdleTimeWaster"
        Me.Text = "Idle Time Waster"
        gbStats.ResumeLayout(False)
        gbStats.PerformLayout()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents gbStats As GroupBox
    Friend WithEvents lblHWPerClickTitle As Label
    Friend WithEvents lblCPSTitle As Label
    Friend WithEvents lblTotalHWTitle As Label
    Friend WithEvents btnUserClick As Button
    Friend WithEvents lblTotalHW As Label
    Friend WithEvents lblCPS As Label
    Friend WithEvents timerCPS As Timer
    Friend WithEvents lblUp1lvlName As Label
    Friend WithEvents lblUp2lvlName As Label
    Friend WithEvents lblUp2lvl As Label
    Friend WithEvents btnUp1 As Button
    Friend WithEvents btnUp2 As Button
    Friend WithEvents lblUp1CostName As Label
    Friend WithEvents lblUp2CostName As Label
    Friend WithEvents lblUp1Cost As Label
    Friend WithEvents lblUp2Cost As Label
    Friend WithEvents NotifyIcon1 As NotifyIcon
    Friend WithEvents lblClickValue As Label
    Friend WithEvents lblUp1lvl As Label
End Class
```

### this error comes up when i build it:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Idle_time_Waster.formIdleTimeWaster.lblUp1lvl.get returned Nothing
```

as of posting this question am going to try seeing if updating VS fixes the problem

Comment: A `NullReferenceException` is a run-time exception, not a compilation error. That means that it is occurring in code being executed as part of the build. It's probably something to do with the extension you mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried disabling that comments extension?

Comment: @CaiusJard no but I'll try that now

Comment: @CaiusJard disabling the `Better Comments` extention didn't work, I also tried disabling my other extentions (though this error never happened before with them all enabled I thought I'd give it a try) and that didn't work either

Comment: And when you say "build it" you surely mean "clicking project menu, going to build.." and clicking nothing else. You do not mean "clicking the play icon and running the app". You absolutely are not running the app and this error is definitely happening during the building of the app not the running of it (which are two very different things)?

Comment: @CaiusJard when I 'build' the program it errors before it finished building, but when I 'debug'(not starting the application just scanning the code) I hear the success sound then the error comes up

Comment: Can you bundle the entire project up into a zip file for us to look at or does it contain too much sensitive stuff? Interested to know if my machine does the same. ps; there's a "success sound"?!

Comment: @CaiusJard I can compress it and send it tommorow,

Comment: @CaiusJard I have an extention 'make the sound's that adds sound effects for different things, one of those things is building succeeded

Comment: @CaiusJard i double check the code and it has personal info stuff in it so i can't send a zip of it, is there any specific part of code you need that i can send?

Comment: Can you duplicate the project (copy paste the folder) and strip it all out? We don't need connection strings, emails, contents of AssemblyInfo citing real person names etc

Comment: @CaiusJard K I'll get to it when I have time